# How can I install qt5 to Debian using commandline?

Tags: qt, debian, qt5

I need to install Qt5 to my Debian using commandline. How can I do that?

My system:
debian 2.6.30-vortex86mx-yh

I am  trying to install using qt online installer from qt-project.org.
But after ./qt.run I get this error:

```
libstdc++.so.6 version glibcxx_3.4.11 not found
```

I try to install libstdc++6. but Debian said it is already newest version.

`cat /etc/issue` result is:

```
Debian 5.0
```

Also my debian has no gui. I have to do it using commandline.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command for installing from default debian 5 repository:

```
#apt install g++
#apt install qtcreator
#apt install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

Comment: Add some description about the code it would help better than a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the qt-installer in a decent debian version. Get Version by:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

On older versions or "unsupported" versions you can still download the sources and build the libraries yourself, which is probably your way to go, since the vortex86-builds are pretty limited in compiler flags. Compiling is rather easy, depending on your needs. The configure script itself gives you a lot of hints regarding possible flags.

Another alternative is to find a user-managed repository that has QT5 for your debian version and add this repository to your `sources.lst`, so you could perform a `apt-get install libqt5`.